# Compare associative array keys and values for checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox, cakephp-1.3

I have a web form with checkboxes for Event Spaces.

[image: checkboxes]

The checkbox values are grabbed from one table in my database "facility_event_charges":

[image: facility event charges]

Let's say I check 5 and 6, "Audio Visual Equipment" and "Audio Visual Technician" and submit my form.

This will save the id(s) to a separate table that I have for that "Event Space"
Let's say my "Event Space" has an ID of 63. The lookup table now has two entries for my id since I checked 2 of the checkboxes:

[image: lookup table]

All is good and saved.
Now, let's say I need to actually edit the charges associated with this space.

When I click edit, my webform renders the form fields BUT the checkboxes are empty!! Why? Because it is grabbing the data from my "facility_event_charges" table.

I need to compare this table data (array) with the data saved in my lookup table (array) to figure out which values are in common and render a check in those checkboxes.

Desired result in my edit space webform would have those checked
[image: checked]

My checkbox "charges" array:

```
array(6) { 
[1]=> string(9) "Officials" 
[2]=> string(6) "Ushers" 
[3]=> string(19) "Additional Staffing" 
[4]=> string(16) "Special Lighting" 
[5]=> string(22) "Audio Visual Equipment" 
[6]=> string(23) "Audio Visual Technician" 
}
```

--
I can also generate the charges in this:

```
array(6) { 
[0]=> array(1) { ["FacilityEventCharge"]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["type"]=> string(9) "Officials" } } 
[1]=> array(1) { ["FacilityEventCharge"]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["type"]=> string(6) "Ushers" } } 
[2]=> array(1) { ["FacilityEventCharge"]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["type"]=> string(19) "Additional Staffing" } } 
[3]=> array(1) { ["FacilityEventCharge"]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["type"]=> string(16) "Special Lighting" } } 
[4]=> array(1) { ["FacilityEventCharge"]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "5" ["type"]=> string(22) "Audio Visual Equipment" } } 
[5]=> array(1) { ["FacilityEventCharge"]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["type"]=> string(23) "Audio Visual Technician" } } }
```

My lookup table array:

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> array(1) { ["EventCharge"]=> array(1) { ["facility_event_charges_id"]=> string(1) "5" } } 
[1]=> array(1) { ["EventCharge"]=> array(1) { ["facility_event_charges_id"]=> string(1) "6" } } 
}
```

--
I've been unsuccessful in my attempts - tried php array_intersect
array_intersect_assoc
array_map('array_diff_assoc')

I need to loop through the checkbox charges array and find a match from the lookup table array, when it matches, mark the checkbox "checked".

Anyone have any working examples I could test out?
The checkbox charges array **key** is what would need to match the **"facility_event_charges_id"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per you array given above you can compare like this

for example Lets `take $charge array as`

```
array(6) { 
[1]=> string(9) "Officials" 
[2]=> string(6) "Ushers" 
[3]=> string(19) "Additional Staffing" 
[4]=> string(16) "Special Lighting" 
[5]=> string(22) "Audio Visual Equipment" 
[6]=> string(23) "Audio Visual Technician" 
}
```

take `$lookup array as`

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> array(1) { ["EventCharge"]=> array(1) { ["facility_event_charges_id"]=> string(1) "5" } } 
[1]=> array(1) { ["EventCharge"]=> array(1) { ["facility_event_charges_id"]=> string(1) "6" } } 
}
```

You can `compare both array like below`

```
$charges = array(
    1 => "Officials",
    2 => "Ushers",
    3 => "Additional Staffing",
    4 => "Special Lighting",
    5 => "Audio Visual Equipment",
    6 => "Audio Visual Technician"
);
$lookup = array(
    array("EventCharge" => array(
            "facility_event_charges_id" => "5"
        )
    ), array(
        "EventCharge" => array(
            "facility_event_charges_id" => "6"
        )
    )
);
$lookup = array_column(array_column($lookup, 'EventCharge'), 'facility_event_charges_id');
foreach ($charges as $key => $value) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="charges" value="' . $key . '" '.(in_array($key, $lookup)?"checked":"").'>';
    echo '<label>'.$value.'<label>';
}
```

**Edit**

If array_column() is not supported than you can create array using loop like below and test

```
$arr=array();
foreach ($lookup as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        $arr[]=$v['facility_event_charges_id'];
    }    
}
foreach ($charges as $key => $value) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="charges" value="' . $key . '" '.(in_array($key, $arr)?"checked":"").'>';
    echo '<label>'.$value.'<label>';
}
```

Comment: I'll try but array_column needs php 5.5. Received a Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_column()

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted this edited answer and awarded the bounty. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

This works...

But it will change based on how exactly you end up building the arrays... but that should only require a change in the if-then statement and possibly a change in the value of i (the index variable).

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form>
<?php

// assume you build this based on a sql query
// you don't need to use the primary key for the
// array index
$charges[0]="Officials";
$charges[1]="Ushers";
$charges[2]="Additional Staffing";
$charges[3]="Special Lighting";
$charges[4]="AV Equipment";
$charges[5]="AV Technician";


// your array of eventcharges
// select facility_event_charges_id from tbl where facility_event_spaces_id='63'
// loop thru the result of teh query make a simple array of your evencharge ids
// gonna hardcode mine out of laziness
// since php is typeless we can use strings to compare to ints
// directly as long as we use == and not ===
// and in_array() (used below) goes with loose comparison too
$ec[]="4";
$ec[]="5";

// now we have an array of our descriptions
// and an array of the already selected choices
// from the db data

for($i=0;$i<count($charges);$i++){
    print('<input type="checkbox" name="charges" value="'.$i.'" ');
    if(in_array($i,$ec)){
        print("checked");
    }
    print(" > ".$charges[$i]."<br />");
}

?>
</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I'm trying this but having a problem getting my array to be like $ec[]
$ec is
array(2) { 
[0]=> array(1) { ["EventCharge"]=> array(1) { ["facility_event_charges_id"]=> string(1) "5" } } 
[1]=> array(1) { ["EventCharge"]=> array(1) { ["facility_event_charges_id"]=> string(1) "6" } } 
}

Comment: Post how you are building the arrray that contains (eventually) your event charges.  Probably a much easier way to do it so it will be a very simple array like my $ec

Comment: $sqlFields = array("facility_event_charges_id");
  $sqlConditions = array("facility_event_spaces_id"=>$id);
  $sqlOrderBy = array("facility_event_spaces_id asc"); 
  $sqlParams = array('fields'=>$sqlFields,'conditions'=>$sqlConditions,'order'=>$sqlOrderBy);
  $ec = $this->EventCharge->find('all',$sqlParams);
  $this->set('ec',$ec);

Comment: find all by space id - in this case id = 63

Comment: that results in
array(2) { 
[0]=> array(1) { ["EventCharge"]=> array(1) { ["facility_event_charges_id"]=> string(1) "5" } } 
[1]=> array(1) { ["EventCharge"]=> array(1) { ["facility_event_charges_id"]=> string(1) "6" } } 
}

Comment: So then you could build an $ec like I used by 

`for($i=0;$i<count($yourResult);$i++){
  $ec[$i]=$yourResult[$i]["EventCharge"]["facility_event_charges_id"]
}

print_r($ec);`

Comment: well yes, I have that in there but the array is not as simple as yours. So, looking at in_array, I understand that to look to see if $i (0-5) is in my $ec array? This is off by 1 but I would expect it to find '5' and put a check there. It needs to loop through and in this case mark checked for 5 and 6.

I will add another array of all the charge types I can generate up above

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use following code.i assumed that you have got $arr=array('5','6'); from database.so you can us as follows

```
<?php
$arr=array('5'=>'Audio Visual Equipment','6'=>'Audio Visual Technician');
$arr=array_keys($arr);//if you have associated array
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"> 
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" name="charges" value="1" <?=in_array('1', $arr)?'checked=true':''?>> Officials<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="charges" value="2" <?=in_array('2', $arr)?'checked=true':''?>> Ushers<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="charges" value="3" <?=in_array('3', $arr)?'checked=true':''?>> Additional Staffing <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="charges" value="4" <?=in_array('4', $arr)?'checked=true':''?>> Special Lighting <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="charges" value="5" <?=in_array('5', $arr)?'checked=true':''?>> Audio Visual Equipment<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="charges" value="6" <?=in_array('6', $arr)?'checked=true':''?>> Audio Visual Technician<br>
</body>
</html>
```